# Polyline is not getting drawn on the google map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-polyline

I have a set of LatLngs in my arraylist and i want to draw a polyline on to the map using these LatLngs.I am adding my latlngs to PolylineOptions and then drawing the polyline. But the polyline is not getting drawn.

This is my code snippet.

```
PolylineOptions options = new  
PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.RED).geodesic(true);

for (int k = 0; k < latLngs.size()-1; k++) {
LatLng point = latLngs.get(i);                 
options.add(point);
}
mMap.addPolyline(options);
```

Comment: you can just use options.addAll(latLngs); - also you might want to verify that latLngs is not empty.

Comment: Minor thing as well, your loop will end one item early. You're checking against less-than the length minus 1. So if you have an array of length 5, so when your loop gets to item 5, index 4, it will end before running the conditional statement inside. You only need to subtract 1 from your length if you're checking against less-than-or-equal-to. In this case, you can just check if the index is less-than the length.

Comment: my latlngs arraylist is not empty Angel Koh

Comment: yes i have changed the @idratherbeintheair

Comment: Anything in the fact that your loop for adding the points is using `k` as your index variable, and you are pulling your items from the ArrayList using `i`?

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: now i have added all the latlngs like this options.addAll(latLngs);

Comment: but still polyline is not getting drawn

Comment: Post your entire activity/fragment code. You're seeing the map, right? Just no polyline? Where are you adding the polylines to the map?

Comment: Its working fine now thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().width(10).color(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_primary)); 
options.add(new LatLng(23.229163, 72.658540)); 
options.add(new LatLng(23.212809, 72.648331)); 
options.add(new LatLng(23.214441, 72.644304));

Polyline polyLine = mMap.addPolyline(options);  
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(23.229163, 72.658540), 17.0f));
```